# NaN x and y values in Pack Layout nodes using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, circle-pack

I'm trying to make a circle packing chart using d3.js. The problem is that nodes have NaN values in the x and y properties, so all the circles have   *transform="**translate(NaN,NaN)**"*

Json Data:

```
 var data = {
     "name": "flare",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "analytics",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "cluster",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
          {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "graph",
         "children": [
          {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534}
         ]
        }]
    }]
    };
```

Script:

```
    var diameter = 200;
    var w = 500;
    var h = 400;

    var pack = d3.layout.pack()
                .size(500,400);

    var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
                .attr({width:w,height:h})
                .append("g").attr("transform","translate("+w/2+","+h/2+")");

    var nodes = pack.nodes(data);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                        .attr("r",function(d){return d})
                        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";});
```

Could anyone explain why the X and Y node values are NaN? I've created a jsFiddle with the data and the script I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/nm9Lozn2/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change the argument you pass to `.size` of `pack` to an array. and also add `.value` since your data doesn't have value attributes:

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#value
>
> If value is specified, sets the value accessor to the specified function. If value is not specified, returns the current value accessor, which assumes that the input data is an object with a numeric value attribute:

so:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .size(500,400);
```

to:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .size([500,400])
            .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Comment: How can we add value in V4 of D3

Answer (score 1):

There's probably several causes for this problem, let me add another possibility, which I just encountered. I was seeing the same issue where `d3.layout.pack` was producing `NaN` for the coordinates. In my case the issue was that some of the values in my data were negative. Once I made sure they were all zero or greater, it began working fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction. In my case it was caused by values of 0.